# Regular Expression to change AssemblyVersion in AssemblyInfo.vb

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am trying to get the version number out of the AssemblyInfo.vb file and replace it with a number that I choose.

```
Dim text as string = string.empty
Using sr As New StreamReader("C:\foo\AssemblyInfo.vb")
    text = sr.ReadToEnd()
    Dim fileVerReg As New Regex("^[^']*(AssemblyVersion[(""].)([^""]*)")
    Dim m As Match = fileVerReg.Match(text)
    If m.Success Then
         MsgBox(m.Groups(2).Value)
    End If
 End Using
```

This is just for me to try and get the version, ideally I would need to be doing a replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following VS addon, [Versioning Controlled Build](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/versioningcontrolledbuild.aspx), much better than a regex. I use it on both my development machine and my build machine (both VS 2008 currently, but used it on VS 2005 previously).

Comment: Nice find, much better than my quick program that I made.

Comment: @Ryan - I thought the same when I found it!